# Is the callback function in SDL_Audio_Spec called SDLAudio_Spec.freq times a second?

Tags: audio, callback, sdl

Is the callback function in SDL_Audio_Spec called SDLAudio_Spec.freq times a second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is only called enough times to output SDLAudioSpec.freq samples per second. How many times it will be called also depends on the buffer size(SDLAudioSpec.samples).